# Android область видимости и взаимодействия

Tags: java, android, область-видимости

У меня есть одна функция которая работает как сервис, но она не срабатывает, я не могу понять почему. Вот код функции:

```
public class TimeToServer extends Service {
boolean yes_sinchron = false;
boolean isOnline = true;

public TimeToServer() {
    Timer newTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask time_to_Srever = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("TimeToServer", "Работаю");
            long time_to_server = mSettings.getLong(TimeObn, 0);

            if (time_to_server != 0) {
                byte time_delay_Sinhron = (byte) mSettings.getInt(SettingSinhron, 2);
                switch (time_delay_Sinhron) {
                    case (0):
                        time_to_server += 600000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 10 минут");
                        break;
                    case (1):
                        time_to_server += 1800000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 30 минут");
                        break;
                    case (2):
                        time_to_server += 3600000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 1 час");
                        break;
                    case (3):
                        time_to_server += 10800000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 3 часа");
                        break;
                    case (4):
                        time_to_server += 21600000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 16 часов");
                        break;
                    case (5):
                        time_to_server += 43200000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 12 часов");
                        break;
                    case (6):
                        time_to_server += 86400000;
                        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Проверям переодичность 24 часа");
                        break;

                    default: break;
                }

                long time_Now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (time_Now >= time_to_server) {
                    yes_sinchron = true;
                    Log.d("TimeToServer", "Надо начинать синхронизацию");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    newTimer.schedule(time_to_Srever, 0, 120000);
    if (yes_sinchron) {
        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Запуск синхронизации");
        if (Sinchron_bd.performClick()) {
            isOnline = false;
            yes_sinchron = false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_conn_internet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TimeToServer", "Нету интернета");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Еще не время");
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Верните канал связи в службу.
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Сама проблема заключается в том что yes_sinchron не определяется как true хотя должна. А если точнее то это if else вообще не отрабатывает.

Comment: Конструкторы сервисов, фрагментов, активити, ресиверов и прочих системных элементов нельзя использовать, т.к. они вызываются системой. Попробуйте перенести код из конструктора в onStartCommand

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я перенёс, но без результата.

Comment: Даже else не выполняется?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да она вообще пропускаетя, что очень странно

Comment: Вы тут конкретно замудрили, упростите реализацию, перепишите все с нуля. Каждый раз инкрементируя `time_to_server` время куда-то в бесконечность улетает, по-моему.

Comment: Возможно, у вас InstantRun сбоит. Попробуйте его отключить

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я нечего не мудрил все очень просто в time_to_server берется время прошлой синхронизации потом прибавляется определенный промежуток и вычисляется надо делать синхронизацию или нет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что за InstantRun??

Comment: @Moonwolf45, это хитрая настройка в студии, которая ускоряет отображение изменений в коде. Иногда она сбоит и не обновляет приложение на девайсе. В итоге вы код меняете, а он не меняется)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хммм, щас поищим посмотрим, но дело наврятли в ней

Comment: Замудрил. Таймер меняет флаг, который проверяется в конструкторе, где этот таймер создается и запускается. Это не может работать в принципе.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja окей, тогда можешь предложить как мне сделать лучше??

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я изменил InstantRun, но результат тот же, не работает

Comment: Переделайте чтобы таймер не флаги выставлял, а саму работу делал, тогда будет работать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не возможно, поскольку таймер работает в отдельном потоке, я не могу заставить его нажимать кнопку, а также я не могу заставить его запускать функции которые не являются статичными

Comment: Это называется проблемой архитектуры :) Надо переделывать, используя другой подход к проблеме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это не будет срабатывать никогда.

```
newTimer.schedule(time_to_Srever, 0, 120000);
if (yes_sinchron) {
    // ...
}
```

Флаг `yes_sinchron` будет всегда `false`.

Нельзя ожидать результат асинхронной операции и еще запущенной по расписанию сразу после факта запуска.